# Trigger to update parent's field

Tags: apex, triggercontext, before-trigger, trigger

I have a requirement:

1) Match field(number) is created on name

2) Opportunity Match(number) is created on vehicle.

3) Develop a trigger ::

1) on Insert - The value in "Opportunity Match" field on the vehicle record is matched against the "Match" field of the name
               If match is found , Populate the name Name field with the Matching name record Id

2) on Update -  If the value is changed on update then again run the above logic.

eg:: User creates a new vehicle record -> user put some value on the "name Match" field like 1
When user save the vehicle record the Opportunity Name field should populate the name Name of the name with 
1 value in the Match field.

I have made a lookup field on Vehicle__c name 'Opportunity__c' I am doing this way

```
trigger MatchField on Vehicle__c (before insert, before update) 
{
List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<opportunity>();
Set<Id> oppId = new Set<Id>();
for(Vehicle__c v : trigger.new)
{
    oppId.add(v.opportunity__c);
}
Map<id,Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<id,Opportunity>([Select id, Match__c, name From Opportunity Where Id IN : oppId]);
for(Vehicle__c v : Trigger.new)
{
  if(v.Opportunity_Match__c == opportunity.Match__c)
    {
        opportunity opp = new opportunity();
        opp.id = oppMap.get(v.opportunity__c).id;
        opp.name = oppMap.get(v.opportunity__c).name + ' ' + string.valueOf(v.Opportunity_Match__c);
        oppList.add(opp);
    }
}
update oppList;
}
```

Comment: You are facing any issues.@Anzar

Comment: on this line if(v.Opportunity_Match__c == opportunity.Match__c) error is coming  Invalid foreign key relationship: Vehicle__c.opportunity at line 12 column 36

Comment: Please check once opportunity.Match__c how it will get directly.i think you forgot to use your map like oppMap.get(v.id).Match__c @Anzar

Comment: @Pavantej It worked...but why if(v.Opportunity_Match__c == v.opportunity.Match__c) was not working.I am accessing its parent Opportunity.???
I mean v.opportunity.Match__c and oppMap.get(v.opportunity__c).Match__c are same statement..arn't they not ????

Comment: I the question your wrote like (v.Opportunity_Match__c == opportunity.Match__c).But in this statement how you can access directly writing opportunity.because you working on a trigger for vehicle.Let me know any issues.Thank god my answer works for you.I will post the answer please close the thread.@Anzar

Comment: Do you mean to do `if(v.Opportunity_Match__c == oppMap.get(v.Opportunity_Match__c).ID)`, what is `opportunity.Match__c`??

Comment: if you have two vehicles in the same batch that point at the same Opportunity, the update will fail with duplicate sobjects with same ID.  Perhaps your business logic elsewhere ensures this can't happen but if not, rethink the building of the `oppList`

Comment: @Pavantej please post an answer so that I can close this thread.